# How to disable Windows Optical Burning Services on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, burning, windows-services, blu-ray, nero

I have calibration power issues with my BluRay RW unit and Nero. In past I have fixed this issue deactivating Windows IMAPI service that is a built in feature that allows you to use udf file system with optical discs but seems causing problems with certain hardware\software configurations. 
I have Windows 10 creation update but I cannot find this service listed anywhere so I cannot figure how to disable it.
This feature is enabled for sure since all `imapi.dll` are in my System32 folder and all built-in udf burning features are active and working when I insert a blank disc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable it with the Group Policy Editor:

1. Press the Windows button
2. Type: `Edit Group Policy` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigate to: 
    Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, File Explorer
4. Double-click on `Remove CD Burning Features`
5. Select `Disabled` and click OK
6. Reboot

Alternatively, you can modify the setting directly from the registry:

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Value: NoCDBurning (DWORD): 
  `0` (or deleted): Users are able to use Windows Explorer CD burning
  `1`: All features in Windows Explorer that allow you to use your CD writer are removed.

Source: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5942-burning-cd-dvd-enable-disable.html

Note: The source is for Windows 7 and 8.1, but I confirmed the functionality still works in Windows 10.

Comment: Seems that is missing the template relative to CD Burning Features in my Windows 10 Creation update.

Comment: Version 21H1 -- the Group Policy option has been moved to "User Configuration". Same subfolder.